# Find all $k,n,m\in\mathbb N$ for which $\cos^k(\frac{2\pi}n)=\cos(\frac{2\pi}m).$

Tags: trigonometry, galois-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all $1<k,n,m\in\mathbb N$ for which $\cos^k(\frac{2\pi}n)=\cos(\frac{2\pi}m).$

The case where $k=2$ has been solved in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616527/find-all-4n-m-in-mathbb-n-for-which-cos2-frac2-pin-cos-frac2-pim).
I've not been able to  find any new cases for $k>3$.
We know that $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q\left[\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)\right]\to \mathbb Q\left[\root k \of{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)}\right]$ is of degree $k\varphi(m)$. So, $k\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$.